# Update table using join SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to update several columns of a table, but one piece of information is stored in another table, so I'm assuming I need to join them but I'm unsure how to. Basically I need to update the job title where the office is T06 and the start date where the original start_date was '05-FEB-09, 08:00' for the staff whose last name is Parker

So far I have:

```
UPDATE JOB
SET JOB_TITLE = 'Head of Technology'
WHERE OFFICE = 'T06' 
AND SET START_DATE = '26-JUN-17, 08:00'
WHERE START_DATE = '05-FEB-09, 08:00'
FROM JOB
JOIN STAFF
ON JOB.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID
WHERE STAFF.LAST_NAME = 'Parker';
```

Comment: Please show what tables the columns are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be

```
update job
set job_title = 'Head of Technology',
    start_date = '26-JUN-17, 08:00'
where office = 'T06'
      and start_date = '05-FEB-09, 08:00'
      and staff_id =(select staff_id
                     from staff
                     where last_name = 'Parker'
                    );
```

However, it might need to be modified (`START_DATE` condition is strange).

Also, it is unclear what `START_DATE` datatype is. *Should* be `DATE`, but your code suggests a string (`VARCHAR2`).

---

Alternative #1 (note `TO_DATE`) function:

```
update job
set job_title = 'Head of Technology',
    start_date = to_date('26-JUN-17, 08:00', 'dd-mon-yy, hh24:mi')
where office = 'T06'
      and start_date = to_date('05-FEB-09, 08:00', 'dd-mon-yy, hh24:mi')
      and staff_id =(select staff_id
                     from staff
                     where last_name = 'Parker'
                    );
```

---

Alternative #2 (note `CASE` and absence of `START_DATE` in `WHERE` clause):

```
update job
set job_title = 'Head of Technology',
    start_date = case when start_date = to_date('05-FEB-09, 08:00', 'dd-mon-yy, hh24:mi')
                           then         to_date('26-JUN-17, 08:00', 'dd-mon-yy, hh24:mi')
                      else start_date
                 end
where office = 'T06'
      and staff_id =(select staff_id
                     from staff
                     where last_name = 'Parker'
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE JOB
    SET JOB_TITLE = 'Head of Technology'
        OFFICE = 'T06',
        START_DATE = '26-JUN-17, 08:00'
WHERE START_DATE = '05-FEB-09, 08:00' AND
      OFFICE = 'T06' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STAFF
              WHERE JOB.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID AND
                    STAFF.LAST_NAME = 'Parker' 
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

The most native way is to use [*updatable join view*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#ADMIN11782)

Simple make you join and select all relevant columns, than add `UPDATE` modifying the join.

```
update (
 select job.*
 FROM JOB
 JOIN STAFF
 ON JOB.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID
 WHERE STAFF.LAST_NAME = 'Parker')
set JOB_TITLE = 'Head of Technology',
START_DATE = '26-JUN-17, 08:00'
```

The only requirement is that the column `STAFF_ID`  in `STAFF` table is backed with a unique index (e.g. primary key).

Without this you get the ERROR `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`

This way of `UPDATE` is very usefull if you need to update with a value from the joined table (not your case).